# Event not firing in nested components in Prado ? (Attached with an invalid event handler )

Tags: drop-down-menu, prado

I have a TDataList that has a XActiveDataGrid inside it. In XActiveDataGrid, there is a TDropDownList. I want to fire an action if the user change the selectedindex of the dropdownlist but it doesnt work. Thats my TDropDownList

```
   <com:TTemplateColumn Id="Reminder" HeaderText="Reminder" HeaderStyle.Width="20%" >
            <prop:ItemTemplate >
                <com:TDropDownList CssClass="combobox4" ID="ReminderDropdown" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Page.SourceTemplateControl.ChangeReminder" 
                 SelectedValue="<%# $this->parent->DataItem['Reminder'] %>">
                    <com:TListItem Text="No Reminder" Value="No Reminder" />
                    <com:TListItem Text="1 week" Value="1 week" />
                    <com:TListItem Text="2 weeks" Value="2 weeks" />
                    <com:TListItem Text="1 month" Value="1 month" />
                    <com:TListItem Text="2 months" Value="2 months" />
                </com:TDropDownList>
            </prop:ItemTemplate>
        </com:TTemplateColumn>
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that the events of the dynamicly created controls arn't registered, may [THIS](http://www.pradoframework.com/forum/index.php?topic=12137.0) helps.